# Different x values with sharex

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have two time indexed Series, and I want to plot them and share the x axis (the range of FEATURE contains the range of X):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

start = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 08:00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 10:00:00')
X = pd.Series([1, 2, 3],
              [pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 08:30:00'),
               pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:30:00'),
               pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 10:30:00')],
              )
FEATURE = pd.Series([0, 4, 2],
                    [pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 08:00:00'),
                     pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:00:00'),
                     pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 10:00:00')]
                    )

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='all')
X[start:end].plot(ax=ax1)
FEATURE.plot(ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

But only FEATURE is shown. If I put X last, then only X is shown.

Comment: X and Feature seem to not have the same range on the x axis. Therefore sharing the axes may not make too much sense in this case. Since `compute_feature` is a secret here, there is not much more one can tell.

Comment: compute_feature is a exponential weighted moving average, but I don't think it helps. It would make sense: I want to represent X on the axis of Feature.

Comment: Could be, nobody knows. If you supply a [mcve], people can test it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you, I did that.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with sharex. If you leave that out, there are still strange things happening (only one axis has ticks). I am not sure what exactly causes this but will have a deeper look into it in a bit.

Comment: In fact, idk why, but in my real code, leaving sharex out gives ticks for both... But the problem with sharex is certainly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to plot the data with matplotlib instead of using the pandas plot wrapper.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

start = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 08:00:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 10:00:00')
X = pd.Series([1, 2, 3],
              [pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 08:30:00'),
               pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:30:00'),
               pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 10:30:00')],
              )
FEATURE = pd.Series([0, 4, 2],
                    [pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 08:00:00'),
                     pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:00:00'),
                     pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 10:00:00')]
                    )

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='all') 

ax1.plot(X.index, X.values)
ax2.plot(FEATURE.index, FEATURE.values)

loc = mdates.MinuteLocator([0,30])
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
plt.show()
```

[image]